# C# compile error: “X is inaccessible due to its protection level”

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, access-levels

when c# gives this compile error?

> 'Favorite.Favorites.FavoriteCollection' is inaccessible due to its protection level

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Favorites objFavorites = new Favorites(); 

    objFavorites.ScanFavorites();
    foreach (WebFavorite objWebFavorite in objFavorites.FavoriteCollection)
    {
        ListViewItem objListViewItem = new ListViewItem();
        objListViewItem.Text = objWebFavorite.Name;
        objListViewItem.SubItems.Add(objWebFavorite.Url);
        lstFavorites.Items.Add(objListViewItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `Favorite.Favorites.FavoriteCollection` declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This compile-time error means that the property you are trying to access is not `public` and the only way to access it is by either modifying its [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(VS.71).aspx) or using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx).

Comment: this problem is just in form1.cs

Comment: @arash, and what you expect us to do?

Comment: @arash: The problem is in form1.cs because that's where you access the `FavoriteCollection` property of `objFavorites`. You need to modify the definition of that property if you want other classes (like `Form1`) to be able to access it.

Answer (score 3):

When it's not visible enough to reach: If, for example, the class is in another project and the visibility is `interal` or lower (`protected` or `private`), you won't be able to use it. You'll have to change it to public in such a case:

```
public class FavoriteCollection
{
...
}
```

Comment: ita an arraylist.i used it in another project,so i renamed in to another name but it also has the same error