# Public static class from another project "is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Tags: c#, xna

In my C# solution I've got multiple projects.

One of them is OdulaProject (XNA WP7 game). (I)
The primary project is Editor (WinForms app) (II)

In (I) is this piece of code:

```
namespace OdulaProject.GameCore.Resources
{
    public class MyLevel
    {
        // TODO: remove!!!
        public static Vector3 GetFieldPosition(Point coordinates)
        {
            return new Vector3(coordinates.X * MyGameConstants.FieldSize.X, coordinates.Y * MyGameConstants.FieldSize.Y, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In (II) I've got a reference to (I) and this piece of code:

```
using OdulaProject.GameCore.Resources;

...

MyLevel.GetFieldPosition(new Point(0, 0));
```

And I'm still getting en error:

> 'OdulaProject.GameCore.Resources.MyLevel' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

Comment: did you try to rebuild your whole solution?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a duplication of OdulaProject.GameCore.Resources.MyLevel by mistake?

Comment: Yeah, tried to rebuild with no success...

The duplicate? Guess it should be duplicates free. But I'm sharing OdulaProject project between two solutions (game solution and editor solution) - could it be a problem?

Comment: what happens when you comment out your MyLevel class an try to rebuild? and if you still get the same error, where does 'Go to Definition' take you?

Comment: 'Go to Definition' takes me directly to the code mentioned above.
And when I comment the whole class out, I still get the same error while rebuilding (inaccessible due to its protection level).

Comment: And when I try to 'Go to the definition' while the whole class is commented out I got an error "Cannot navigate to 'MyLevel'."

Comment: Solution founded: In solution I had got other similar problems (some classes were inaccessible due to its protection level...) and in one of these (public) classes I used public list of internal classes.

Comment: Making class public should solve this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595380/c-sharp-compile-error-x-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level

Comment: Is MyLevel an instance of the class MyLevel? If so your issue is that you are accessing a static method through an instance of the class. Other then that I see no reason for the code to not be working.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem tricky, but in a solution with multiple projects, some might require public that others don't.   Adding public liberally, to the offending class/static innards can help debug the missing accessibility.

It goes without saying, that these should all be re-evaluated post-hoc.